# Magento invalid email address

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to add my email address in Store Email Address, But it is saying "Invalid email address "admin@mydomain"."
Note that my tld is uncommon.
I think that is the reason for the error message.
I can add .com email address easily btw.

Is there any way to add the email?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, but your suggestions were misleading. 
The error message comes up not from this java script, but app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Email/Address.php

The error is generated from lib/Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php, because it calls hostname verification from Hostname.php in the same directory. 
There you can find in row nr. 117 an array called $_validTlds 
there put your domain ('works' or in my case 'wien'), take care alphabetical order, and quotes and commas. save and try again, 
it will work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

in validation.js you have 
 ['validate-email', 'Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.', function (v) {

```
            return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*\.(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){2,})$/i.test(v)
        }],
```

You will have to play with this regular expression.

if you look into this expression you will find a . jsut remove every thing excluding ] from . till end and should solve.

Comment: Sorry I'm not good at RegExp.
There are three . in that expression. I tried some but nothing did work. The "save config" button stops workin if I edit that line.
My tld is .works
Can you please tell me how should I edit it.
Thanks.